# ember store.find promise not being fulfilled in time

Tags: ember.js

I'm using an ArrayController with an ItemController but I'm having problems with getting my store.find promise fulfilled before the hotelName and hotelAddress properties in my ItemController are used.  Any idea on how I can unsure the store find is fulfilled before returning?   I know the store.find works.  I'm able to see the results but the timing is off.  Thank you.

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: ...,
});

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
    },
    hotelName: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.store.find('hotel', this.get('hotelId')).then(function(hotel) {
            self.set('hotelName', hotel.get('name'));
        });
    }.property('hotelId'),

    hotelAddress: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.store.find('hotel', this.get('hotelId')).then(function(hotel) {
            self.set('hotelAddress', hotel.get('street'));
        });
    }.property('hotelId')
});
```

Comment: This is not idiomatic Ember. You want to define the model hooks in the routes and take advantage of the fact that Ember instantiates the appropriate controllers for you accordingly. The routes are promise aware and therefore you will have access to the model properties via the controllers (which are practically proxies to the model) without worrying about when the promises are fulfilled. Another benefit is that the templates are also promise aware and ember will take care of "unwrapping" the values for you before rendering the templates. Let Ember do things for you and write less code.

Comment: So your saying the itemController (used by an ArrayController) actually has a route thus I can treat like any other controller (and setup the model)?  That would drop dead easy.  I will attempt and follow up with a confirmation/update.

Comment: This doesn't seem to hold true for the arrayController / itemController relationship. The arrayController has its model while the itemController needs to lookup a different model (based on information in the array).  An itemRoute setupController doesn't get called.  I'm going to setup a JSbin poke at it.

Comment: The itemRoute never gets called via the ArrayController's itemControllerLookup method. http://jsbin.com/todiq/1/edit

Comment: I'm thinking in this particular case it might just be easier to tweak my model for reservations so I don't need my itemController to access the store for additional information.  Maybe I'm just approaching the use case incorrectly.

Comment: I successfully managed to get this to work:

Comment: I've updated the source above.